# Is there a better way to nest two jquery selections?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("completed");
    });

    $('ul').on('click', "li span", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
```

Situation - There are new li items with span items are added using a form and I want them to be able to have the behavior all the other li items have.

Is there a better way to do this? The multiple declarations with specifiers seem redundant.

This is my first time using jQuery, not really aware how to go around this redundancy.

Thank You.

Comment: create a [mcve]

Comment: Add event listener only on ul and react on event target. If li, do something, if span, do something else.

Comment: @WaldemarIce how should I handle "this" where it will be different for LI as well as for SPAN.

Comment: Added example with this also. Now with switch - more readable.

Comment: I guess best way to check event.target property. There will be two extra if condition to check the target matches your selector.

Answer (score 0):

Give a class name to the elements and use the same logic by selecting the class.

```
<li class="class-name">Text<span class="class-name"></span></li>

$('ul').on('click', '.class-name', function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();

 if(e.target.nodeName == 'SPAN') {
  // Code for span
 } else if(e.target.nodeName == 'LI') {
  // Code for li
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete example:

```js
$('ul').click(function (e) {
  switch (e.target.nodeName) {
    case 'LI':
      $(e.target).addClass('completed')
      break
    case 'SPAN':
      $(e.target).parent().slideUp(500, function () {
        $(e.target).parent().remove()
      })
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li {
  padding: 3px 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
span {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #f00;
}
.completed {
  color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Todo 1 <span>x</span></li>
  <li>Todo 2 <span>x</span></li>
  <li>Todo 3 <span>x</span></li>
  <li>Todo 4 <span>x</span></li>
  <li>Todo 5 <span>x</span></li>
</ul>
```

PS: Unlike others, this solution registers just one event listener for whole list, regardless of items count.

Answer (score 0):

You could just chain them, jQuery adds those event listeners to the UL anyway, and filters based on `event.target` automagically

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function () {

    $(this).toggleClass("completed");

}).on('click', "li span", function (event) {

    event.stopPropagation();

    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: I think both are on same ul so stoppropragation will not work. https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

Comment: Your solution registers two listeners for every item. Its unnecessary browser overloading.

Comment: @shams.kool - should work fine, jQuery does some magic on that one -> https://jsfiddle.net/x3ss8gve/

Comment: @WaldemarIce - unless you have a million UL's, it doesn't matter, the real performance problem is the check for `event.target`, not the event handlers themselves

Comment: You are wrong, of course. Event object is created once per click, then you can check it against any property. But your solution with UL with just 10 LI, create and register 20 event listeners. And again, it is unnecessary perfomance / sources wasting.

Comment: @WaldemarIce - it's **delegated**, it creates two event handler for each UL, regardless of how many LI's or SPAN's there's are. You could have a million LI's, and this still only creates two event handlers.

Comment: In fact, it's pretty much exactly what you're doing in your answer, but this lets jQuery handle the delegation.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the fiddle. I think if you use plain javascript instead of jQuery, you will definitely agree with one event handler. If you look into implementation of `.on` function in jQuery  it contains some if and event target checking.

Comment: @shams.kool - oh yes, in plain JS it makes sense with just one event handler, and it does in jQuery as well, but two event handlers doesn't really matter much, and jQuery handles all the checking of the `event.target` to make sure it matches the selector etc.